# Iterating Enumeration Object Two Times

Tags: python, list, enumeration

I created an enumeration object, and I iterated a list by means of the enumeration. After that, I tried to do it second time and I could not take any output in the interpreter.

```
myList = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"]
enum = enumerate(myList, 0)

for i in enum:  # this printed the output
    print(i)

for j in enum:  # this did not print the output
    print(j)
```

Why could not I use enum object two times ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate` is an iterator, which means that once it is operated on a single i.e looped over or `next` called, its references to values in memory have been exhausted, thus, a mere empty list (`[]`) will be the result the second time `next` is called on the structure, or `for` applied.

However, to solve this problem, you can either cast the result as a list, or add the contents to another list:

```
val = iter([i**2 for i in range(10)])
new_result = list(val)
>>>[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
#create a new structure: 
val = iter([i**2 for i in range(10)])
other_val = [ for i in val]
```

Or, applying `next`:

```
val = iter([i**2 for i in range(10)])
while True: 
   try:
     v = next(val)
     #do something with v
   except StopIteration:
     break
```

Comment: I would add that you can solve the problem by applying `list`.